# How to create a desktop shortcut to a Windows 8 Modern UI app?

Tags: shortcuts, windows-8, modern-ui

I am using Windows 8 at the moment and I was wondering if there is a way to make a shortcut to a Modern UI (formerly known as Metro UI) application on my desktop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no built-in way to do this. For the apps that come with Windows 8, you can use [MetroApp Link](http://www.makeuseof.com/dir/metroapp-link-create-desktop-shortcuts-for-windows-8-metro-apps); official website (in Italian) [here](http://pasquiindustry.altervista.org/download-metroapp-link-2-0-disponibile-per-il-download). It doesn't currently support apps downloaded through the Store, though.

Comment: [Newer version](http://pasquiindustry.deviantart.com/art/ModernApp-Link-2-3-beta-344126882) (Now called *ModernApp Link*).

Answer (score 26):

All Modern UI apps have a URL protocol associated with them which can be used to launch the app.
You can find find the protocol for a specific app like this:

1. Press Windows+R
2. Type `regedit`
3. Navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Protocol\PackageId`
4. Find the subkey for your app (eg, `AMZNMobileLLC.KindleforWindows8_1.1.0.0_neutral__stfe6vwa9jnbp`)
5. Within that subkey, go to `ActivatableClassId_some long name_\CustomProperties`
6. The `Name` value will tell you the protocol name.

You can then make a shortcut to `name://`. (eg, `kindle://`)

Getting an icon is a little harder.
In the subkey directly under `ActivatableClassId`, you'll find a value named `Icon`, in the format `@{AppIdentifier?ms-resource://AppName/Files/path/to/icon.png}`.
You'll find a PNG icon in `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\AppIdentifier\path/to/icon.png`.
However, you'll need to convert this PNG to an ICO file to use in a shortcut.

Comment: If people are interested, I can write a desktop app that will create shortcuts to arbitrary Modern UI apps, automating these steps.  I'll do that if this answer gets 15 votes.

Comment: Brilliant! You get the bounty :)

Comment: @SLaks you have my vote and I'll really love to see that desktop app. :)

Comment: Amazing answer. I know that this is old, but did you ever maked that desktop app?

Comment: @SLaks - **You have 15 votes**

Comment: @Ramhound: Hmm... I don't have much time now, but I'll try to get this written in the next few weeks.

Comment: There are many Apps in HKCR with protocol defined but I can't find one for App Calculator. Another way similar is to search thu the registry for the value "URL:". However, I still can't find that for Calculator. I'm not sure if it's because it's different on a Win81 I'm now with.

Comment: This answer is not correct, the only packages listed are ones that have registered URI handlers.  A lot of apps have URI handlers registered but not all

Answer (score 3):

1. Right click on your Desktop and select `new->shortcut`.
2. When the dialog window opens enter `%windir%\explorer.exe
   shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}` and name
   your application appropriately.
3. Click on the icon your created and launch the `Applications` window.
4. Select the Metro application to use.

Ref: http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/32777-Launch-Metro-Apps-Directly-from-Desktop

Comment: That seems to create a shortcut to the Applications folder, whereas the OP wants to create a shortcut to a specific Metro app.

Comment: I suppose if he's open to installing software he could use MetroApp Link.

Answer (score 2):

I have found out a solution myself and want to make the answer here to be complete.
It's done by a piece of codes of C# and PowerShell by Tome Tanasovski posted at http://poshcode.org/3740 .

You don't have to understand the codes well to have it worked. The good thing is that I don't need to download some 3rd exe and it's programmable so that I can open up the calculator and PDF viewer with just a single hot key.

1. Open up PowerShell command box, and simply paste all codes copied from the link above.
2. Run

   Get-metroApp
3. A list of AppUserModelId of some guessable app name is listed. E.g., I'm looking for Calculator. The AppUserModelId is "Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App". In the PowerShell command box, run

   start-metroApp Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App

Of course you won't like to invoke Calculator again like this. You can save the commands (not all of them, e.g., the part of function get-metroApp is not needed) to a .ps1 . A shortcut to this .ps1 can then be created to execute it. Finally, placing this shortcut to the start menu folder allows you to assign a hot-key for your app.

Answer (score 0):

Go here: (It's a clear and simple solution for any "modern" app you want to create a shortcut for - I used my shortcut to put in the startup folder so the app opens when i log on.
http://winaero.com/blog/exclusive-how-to-start-a-modern-app-from-desktop-without-going-to-the-metro-start-screen/#comment-5450

Comment: Sorry, here's the link:

Comment: http://winaero.com/blog/exclusive-how-to-start-a-modern-app-from-desktop-without-going-to-the-metro-start-screen/#comment-5450

Answer (score -1):

You can launch them via PowerShell. For example,

```
powershell.exe Start-MetroApp Microsoft.BingNews_8wekyb3d8bbwe!AppexNews
```

Comment: Thanks for the clue though your solution is incomplete.