# make shortcuts on windows 8 desktop

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a desktop shortcut to a Windows 8 Metro app?](https://superuser.com/questions/478975/how-to-create-a-desktop-shortcut-to-a-windows-8-metro-app)

How can I make desktop shortcuts of apps on windows 8.

I can not find any way to make shortcuts of windows store apps and the desktop apps from the new start menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open up Explorer and head to the following path:

> %appdata%\microsoft\windows\Start Menu\Programs\

Once you’re there, you can browse down into one of the folders, though you can probably leave the shortcut in that folder as well.

Comment: this allows programs to be linked to on the desktop, but not true Windows Apps.

Answer (score 1):

Without third party apps it may not be possible. There's the [MetroApp Link 2.0](http://pasquiindustry.altervista.org/download-metroapp-link-2-0-disponibile-per-il-download/) program which could provide a good way to have App shortcuts show up on the Desktop view.

Comment: any way to make shortcuts for desktop apps from the new start menu without third party apps

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.guidingtech.com/13502/metro-apps-desktop-shortcut-taskbar-windows-8/) is a tutorial that explains how to create desktop shortcuts using MetroApp Link.