# Assign a hotkey to run a Windows 8 Modern UI App

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a desktop shortcut to a Windows 8 Modern UI app?](https://superuser.com/questions/478975/how-to-create-a-desktop-shortcut-to-a-windows-8-modern-ui-app)

How can I assign hotkey to launch specific application in windows 8?

For instance, Ctrl+C -> Calculator, etc

For traditional desktop applications, you can set a hotkey in the properties of a shortcut, but what about Modern UI apps?

Comment: Even for normal shortcuts, unless you use something like AutoHotKey to override it, Ctrl+C obviously won't work since it's used for Copy everywhere.