# How do you start a Windows 8 app from the desktop?

Tags: windows, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a desktop shortcut to a Windows 8 Modern UI app?](https://superuser.com/questions/478975/how-to-create-a-desktop-shortcut-to-a-windows-8-modern-ui-app)

How do you start a Windows 8 (used to be "Metro") app from the desktop (not the start screen) through a shortcut or something else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/478975/1503

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways is to install a start menu alternative eg Classic Shell

http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/

This will provide you with a start menu, similar to previous versions of Windows

[image]

You can also pin applications to the taskbar, as with Windows 7 you can right click on any shortcut or tile for a desktop app and select Pin to Taskbar.

[image]

You can also create keyboard shortcuts. The fastest way to launch any program is to assign it to a Ctrl + Alt + Key combination. To assign a keyboard shortcut, you must right click on a shortcut, select properties and then fill in the Shortcut key field under the Shortcut tab.

[image]

If a desktop app doesn’t have a shortcut visible on the desktop, you must find it on the Start screen or in search, right click and select Open File Location. You will then see a shortcut icon for it appear in Explorer.

These are the ways I am aware to access programs from the desktop in Windows 8, there maybe others.

[image]

Comment: That's _completely_ not what he's asking.

Comment: @Simon Thanks for your answer but I'm afraid it's not the one to my problem! I am looking to start a metro app from the desktop. Thanks for your time though.

Comment: @James Oh an actual metro app, apologise for that, i hope you find the answer :)